# Stripe Multi Platform

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment

Is there any possible payment gateway that can handle payment for multiple business and their employee salaries?

I look stripe but it support only a single business and employee with Stripe connect

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple Stripe accounts representing each business and under 1 organization. It's best to reach out to Stripe Support for more clarification though.